# Populating an array with a for loop

Tags: java

Write a for loop to populate array userGuesses with NUM_GUESSES integers. Read integers using Scanner. Ex: If NUM_GUESSES is 3 and user enters 9 5 2, then userGuesses is {9, 5, 2}.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StoreGuesses {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      final int NUM_GUESSES = 3;
      int[] userGuesses = new int[NUM_GUESSES];
      int i;

      for (i=0; i < userGuesses ; ++i) {
         Scanner.nextInt(i);
      }

      for (i = 0; i < userGuesses.length; ++i){
         System.out.print(userGuesses[i] + " ");
      }
   }
}
```

My first loop isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are trying to compare an Array with an integer
2. You are not adding user input in your array
   This is the for loop you are looking for:

   ```
    for (i=0; i < NUM_GUESSES ; ++i) {
        userGuesses[i]=scnr.nextInt();
    }
   ```

Now in condition we are checking `i<NUM_GUESSES` , so we will repeat the loop as many times as NUM_GUESSES, and we will be adding each guesss in the array

Answer (score 0):

Okay! So for your first loop, you are asking for the parameters to be from (I = 0; i < userGuesses.length; i++)

for the body of the loop, you need to use the index ("i") to store the values in your array userGuesses[]. When using the Scanner object you need to refer to the object you created not the Scanner class (use your "scnr" not "Scanner")

e.g. userGuesses[i] = scnr.nextInt();